# Uploading File to S3 in Android using PUT

Tags: android, file-upload, amazon-s3, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload a file to AWS s3. I already have a valid url where the file will be uploaded (provided by server) and so I don't really need AWS credential. I just need to make a PUT request on that url with the file to be uploaded.

Previously I'm using Volley API, I convert the File into byte array and use it as the request body.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToUpload);
        int transferredBytes = 0;
        int totalSize = (int) fileToUpload.length();
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        int bufferLength;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bufferLength = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            transferredBytes += bufferLength;
            progressListener.onProgress(transferredBytes, totalSize);
        }
```

The code is working, but has its flaws. As you can see from the code, there is a progress listener, which is basically a progress for writing the bytes into the OutputStream. I assume this does not mean it's already uploaded yet since by the time the progress is 100% there is a momentary idle state between file upload success/error callback is fired.

Now, I'm moving to Retrofit 2, (together with all network functions in the project). I dont have any issue with the basic REST operation, only for the upload part. I can't find any guide on how to implement it.

I've tried searching but most of the results is either need to use AWS SDK or using Multipart which is not applicable in my requirement.

Basically I have these problems:

- How to implement file upload to a url in Retrofit (PUT)
- How to get a progress listener for the actual uploading, not like my previous code

Comment: Did able to reach AWS S3. If yes what was its error throwing.

Comment: @Murali yes it is uploaded in S3, for the volley api code. no problem on that part. It's just the progress display is flawed. haven't tried it in Retrofit yet as I'm still trying to figure out how to convert my volley api code to retrofit for the upload function

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013552/android-retrofit-2-file-upload?rq=1

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37128246/upload-file-with-retrofit-2?rq=1

Comment: Hi @kishidp, have you found an answer for your issue? I will likely face the same issue soon. Thx